# Sourcetree + Git clone stuck at "Updating files 100%"

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

**Problem**

I am getting stuck at "Updating files: 100%" when cloning a git repo on Windows when using Sourcetree.

**Full output**

```
git -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c filter.lfs.required=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks clone --branch master https://[REDACTED] C:\Users\[REDACTED]
Cloning into 'C:\Users\[REDACTED]'...
Updating files:  11% (1860/16666)
Updating files:  12% (2000/16666)
[...]
Updating files:  98% (16333/16666)
Updating files:  99% (16500/16666)
Updating files: 100% (16666/16666)
Updating files: 100% (16666/16666), done.
```

**Versions**

- Sourcetree: 3.4.8.0
- Git (Embedded): 2.35.0

(Note that I think I had this issue on earlier versions as well a few months ago.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure Sourcetree to **use System git instead of Embedded git** as a workaround.

See `Sourcetree -> Options -> Git -> Git Version`

(Note: Git (System) version is 2.35.1)